# Getting Django query list based on another table

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have models as below:

**Group Model**

```py
class Group(model.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

**GroupMember Model**

```py
class GroupMember(model.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='group_member_group')
    member = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='group_member_user')
```

**Course Model**

```py
class Course(model.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

**GroupCourse Model**

```py
class GroupCourse(model.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='course_group')
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='group_course')
```

**CourseStaff Model**

```py
class CourseStaff(model.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='course_staff_course')
    staff = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='course_staff_user')
```

What I want is to get All the `GroupMember`s that does not exists in `CourseStaff` model for a specific course.

**For example:**
I have total 5 members in `Group A`

- Member 1
- Member 2
- Member 3
- Member 4
- Member 5

I have total 2 course in `Group A`

- Course 1
- Course 2

`Course 1` has two members:

- Member 1
- Member 2

`Course 2` has two members:

- Member 2
- Member 3

What I want is to get `Member 3-5` from `GroupMember` when querying for `Course 1`

Also get `Member 1,4, 5` from `GroupMember` when querying for `Course 2`

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*"What I want is to get All the GroupMembers that does not exists in CourseStaff model for a specific course."*

Your realtions between models are weak. You want to exclude GroupMembers that is no CourseStaff but in GroupMembers there is no relation with CourseStaff. You could do on course field of CourseStaff. But your Course model has no relation with any models. You need to add a field under the Course model to connect a relation.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did. It may not perfect, but it works.

```py
course_staffs = CourseStaff.objects.filter(course_id=course_id).values_list('staff_id')
members = User.objects.filter(~Q(id__in=course_staffs), group_member_user__group_id=group_id)
```